# SonarQube - How to activate source syntax-highlighting after 5.0 migration WITHOUT make another analysis of components?

Tags: sonarqube, upgrade, highlighting, sonarqube-scan

I know that the 5.0 release note say "After the migration, source syntax-highlighting won't be available on a project until it has been successfully analyzed"

BUT, i can't imagine that there is no way to activate just by running another analysis. In fact, when you have thousands of components (it's our case), you can't plan 4500 analysis just to "restore" a basic but helpful functionality ! And it's more true when you know that the majority of theses components wasn't changed since a time ago... :(

So, please, say me that we can write a little batch or program that will do the job without need to pull all the sources ! I don't know how because i don't' understand this limitation of this upgrade (why sources aren't accessible)

Answer (score 0):

You should trust the release notes. Information required for syntax highlighting is computed during analysis. Note that it also requires the language plugins to support this feature. I suggest to upgrade them to latest versions.

Comment: My hope was to know if someone would had developped a program who run again analysis for all projects saved in Sonar in order to reactivate highlight.

Because, if you want to activate this functionnality (navigation in sources in Sonar), you must before 
1. find and load sources from your SCM in the state of the last analysis.
2. run a analysis

And the first step is not so easy when you have thousands of projects !

Really domageable... :(

Comment: Don't expect to benefit from new SonarQube features, including new advanced rules, if you can't analyze your projects !